# Could you generate procedural textures in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

First question, so excuse me if I miss some basic etiquette. I'm messing around in Unity2D with a 2D terrain generator for something like a DnD world map. However, I'd like to texture this map with something along the lines of a procedural paper texture. But googling around hasn't lead me to much help - and so I am wondering what is out there that could assist me in at run-time generating a procedural texture and applying it to a 2D plane.

Comment: I think you are looking for some kind of post-processing effect. They are typically called something like "pencil post-processing effect", "hand drawn post-processing effect" or "sketch post-processing effect".
But I think I never saw one for 2d. There it's probably easier to use something like wave-function collapse and just create the tiles beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It will most likely depend on what exactly you're trying to achieve with this procedural texture.

For instance, why wouldn't a simple tileable texture not be appropriate for this project ?

Shaders are probably what you're looking for, there's plenty of resource out there on how to make diverse kind of textures but learning how to make shaders is not a trivial undertaking and can easily become a project of its own.

So I can't provide much in terms of practical answers but If you were to follow through with this idea I would strongly suggest you check out the [**Shader Graph**](https://unity.com/features/shader-graph)  Unity plugin.
It'll be a more practical way than making the shader yourself, but still no easy task.

[**Get started with Shader Graph**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@5.6/manual/Getting-Started.html#:%7E:text=To%20use%20Shader%20Graph%20you,or%20Unlit%20Shader%20Graph%20Asset.)

Sorry for the lack of usable code snippet.